# C# WPF - Showing 15-20 User Controls with 4-6 TextBlocks each / Performance issues

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, listview, binding

I'm struggling with performance in my WPF application.

I have a ListView i populate with some buttons, which contain a bunch of TextBlocks with bindings.
I managed to get Virtualization going, so it seems the same whether its 20 or 2000 i load.

The problem is between 5 and 20. It simply appears that rendering a bunch of somewhat complicated User Controls, is simply too much for basic sub-par hardware.

This is how my Buttons/UserControls in my ListView looks ->
[ListViewSample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIZ8r.png)

I feel like WPF should be able to render this on sup-par hardware.

This is the xaml for the ListView:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ButtonModels, IsAsync=True}"
                      Margin="0"
                      x:Name="ButtonsListView"
                      VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
                      VirtualizingPanel.IsContainerVirtualizable="True"
                      VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
                      ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                      ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                      SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                      Background="Transparent"
                      BorderThickness="0">

            <ListView.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="ScrollBar">
                    <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ScaleTransform CenterX="0" CenterY="0"
                           ScaleX="3" ScaleY="3" />
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ListView.Resources>
            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <local:UniformGridPanel IsItemsHost="True" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="Auto" Rows="4" Columns="{Binding Columns}" Margin="0">
                    </local:UniformGridPanel>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <Button Height="117" Width="Auto" 
                                Margin="6,0,6,0" 
                                x:Name="MasterButton" 
                                Click="MasterButton_Click"
                                Visibility="{Binding IsVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}"
                                Template="{StaticResource ProductButtonTemplate}"
                                Padding="0">
                                </Button>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle> 
            </ListView>
```

Here is the xaml for the Button template:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="ProductButtonTemplate">
            <UserControl>
                <Grid Background="Transparent">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="26"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Border Grid.Row="0" Background="{Binding HeaderBrush}" CornerRadius="3,3,0,0">
                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="12" 
                                                   Text="{Binding DisplayName}" 
                                                   Foreground="{Binding FontIsWhite, Converter={StaticResource BoolToFontColour}}" 
                                                   FontFamily="{StaticResource DefaultRegular}"
                                                   Padding="8,0,0,0"/>
                </Border>
                <Border Grid.Row="1" Background="{StaticResource LightGrey}" CornerRadius="0,0,4,4" BorderBrush="{StaticResource BorderGrey}" BorderThickness="1">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="35" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <TextBlock  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" 
                                                            FontSize="12" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Text="Nr.:" 
                                                            FontFamily="{StaticResource DefaultFont}"
                                                            VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                                            Foreground="{StaticResource Black}"
                                                            Padding="8,0,0,0"/>
                        <TextBlock  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" 
                                                            FontSize="10" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Text="{Binding Combinations}" 
                                                            FontFamily="{StaticResource DefaultFont}"
                                                            VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                                            Foreground="{StaticResource Black}"
                                                            Padding="8,0,0,0"/>
                        <TextBlock  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" 
                                                            FontSize="10" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Text="{Binding SizeAndColour}" 
                                                            FontFamily="{StaticResource DefaultFont}"
                                                            VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                                            Foreground="{StaticResource Black}"
                                                            Padding="8,0,0,0"/>
                        <Grid Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" 
                                                      Width="24" Height="24"
                                                      VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                                      Margin="8,0,0,0"
                                                      Visibility="{Binding ShowStockValue, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}">
                            <Ellipse Fill="{Binding StockStatus, Converter={StaticResource EnumToBrush}}" Stroke="{StaticResource LightGrey}" StrokeThickness="0.1">
                            </Ellipse>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Stock}" 
                                                               Foreground="{StaticResource White}" 
                                                               FontSize="9" 
                                                               FontFamily="{StaticResource DefaultFont}"
                                                               VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Grid>

                        <TextBlock  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" 
                                                            FontSize="12" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Text="{Binding ProductNr}"
                                                            Foreground="{StaticResource Black}"
                                                            VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                                            FontFamily="{StaticResource DefaultFont}"
                                                            Padding="0,0,8,0"/>
                        <Label Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="13" 
                                                       Padding="0,0,8,8"
                                                       Content="{Binding Price}" 
                                                       Foreground="{StaticResource Black}"
                                                       FontWeight="Bold"
                                                       FontFamily="{StaticResource DefaultFont}"
                                                       VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"
                                                       ContentStringFormat="{}{0:#,0.00}" />
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
            </UserControl>
        </ControlTemplate>
```

tldr; I'm looking for performance tips on how to make this render faster. And this is BEFORE i reach a size in the ListView where my virtualization kicks in (Which works flawlessly)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As always regarding performance, I would recommend using a performance profiler. If for no other reason than to confirm that it is the rendering that takes time, and not some other completely unexpected thing.

Comment: Why do you wrap the template content into a redundant and expensive UserControl? You should not do that. You seem to have implemented a custom Panel. Obviously the panel's virtualization is not properly implemented. How come that 2000 items don't impact the panel's performance but 5 do? You should check this. Take a close look at how the panel behaves with only five children.

Comment: @BionicCode I'm sorry, i must have been unclear.
2000+ or whichever amount is high enough for my virtualization kicks in, DOES impact performance, but not more than the maximum amount of shown objects does(which is 20, in this case).
I just mentioned that to clarify that my virtualization DOES work - the issue with performance comes before i reach my 20 items.

Comment: @JonasH I must admit i'm inexperienced with profiling UI performance in WPF - can you give me some hints on how to approach it? I've tried using the profilers in Visual Studio, but i can only seem to find some general CPU usage.

And in regards to confirming - After disabling and enabling various things on the control, i've narrowed it down to the amount of TextBlocks i have on the control.
If i just have the base control and the top TextBlock, it performs really well, but adding just a few more TextBlocks ruins it. (I tried with static texts too, to exclude bindings)

Comment: I guess I understood you. I'm just wondering why you have no issues with >=20 items but below 20 items you get performance issues. There should be no difference. The panel must behave the same. In fact, virtualization will have the same amount of items rendered: the visible items in the viewport (which you said has a height of 20 items).

Comment: I have mostly used dotTrace. But any decent profiler should be able to give you a breakdown into what methods take time. If any significant time is spent inside your own methods, you might want to investigate why.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a high performance solution - it just wasn't what i would expect to be better performing.

So instead of having one ListView with a binding, changing the data in the binding and repopulating the Listview, i just spawn a ListView for every collection i have.

It seems weird to me, that having a bunch of ListViews and just collapsing and showing them is more effcient, but it performs absolutely flawlessly.